# Opposite of buyer's remorse

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Buyer's remorse is when you have a sense of regret after purchasing something. You may have been coerced into first purchasing the item out of fear or guilt.

What would the opposite of this be?

For example, I bought a pair of shoes and I am extremely content with my purchase. Initially I held no rooted affinity for the shoes, but after awhile, they are undoubtedly the best thing ever

...or

I bought a blender without giving much thought because I needed something to blend all my protein shakes. But now after using it, I just feel like telling the world and updating my status every day reminding everyone how amazing this blender is.

**update:** I asked a coworker and she mentioned *buyer's rejoice*. Is this such a thing? Do people use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you described the blender scenario, I would consider it customer satisfaction.

Comment: Even though the OP has accepted this answer, *customer satisfaction* does not seem to quite capture what was described in the question. One is satisfied if the the thing purchased fulfills the expectations that one had at the time of purchasing it; what is described in the question is, however, a feeling that goes beyond what was expected at the time of purchase.

Answer (score 4):

You are thinking of “post-purchase rationalization”, also known as“choice-supportive bias”.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice-supportive_bias

Answer (score 0):

Terms *windfall* and *godsend* seem relevant.

From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/windfall#Noun), *windfall* has a sense “(figuratively) A sudden large benefit; especially an influx of money”. Also from [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/godsend#Noun), *godsend* means “An unexpected good fortune or benefit; a windfall”.

Consider also the related words  *[gravy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gravy#Noun)* (in sense “Extra benefit”), *[manna](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manna#Noun)*, *[bunce](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bunce)*, and *[bonanza](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bonanza#Noun)*.

Comment: Not the same kind of term.

Answer (score 0):

That's your **"moment of truth"**

What's regularly missing, in our experience, is the spark between the customer and frontline staff members or the product itself—the spark that helps transform wary or skeptical people into strong and committed brand followers.

Comment: "Moment of truth" feels more like the single moment in time, when you test the product and determine its worth. The asker seems to be describing the feeling after such a test has passed with unexpected success.